# How can i plot a graph showing the Current Speed and Direction VS Depth?

Tags: matlab, profile

My title followed. Below is my criteria:

1. Length of the arrow proportional to the magnitude of the current
2. Arrow rotate in 360 degrees about an axis, showing the current directions, toward East-North-West-South.
3. Lastly, depth increases along that axis.

Please see the following figure for description.

[image]

Comment: That's great... so what have you tried? You can also start by sharing some of your data.

Comment: @piresloh7 take a look at quiver3 ()